# Normal subgroup of a totally ordered group

Tags: gr.group-theory, order-theory, linear-orders, ordered-groups

A totally ordered group is a group equipped with a compatible total order, that is, $x\leq y$ and $z\leq t$ imply $x+z\leq y+t$ for all $x,y,z,t$ in the group.
Is it true that every totally ordered group has a nontrivial normal subgroup (not necessarily convex) ?

Comment: You mean, other than the two obvious ones (trivial and improper)?

Comment: You mean, a nontrivial totally ordered group?

Comment: @HJRW the given definition is that of bi-orderable (specified to $x=y$ it means the order is left-invariant and specified to $z=t$ it means it's right invariant).

Comment: @YCor, yes, in the light of Dave's answer I realize that now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Thompson's group F is bi-orderable (or "totally ordered", in your terminology), and its commutator subgroup [F,F] is simple. So [F,F] is an (infinite) bi-orderable simple group. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1688) of Navas and Rivas for a discussion of all the bi-invariant orderings of F, and a reference to a proof that [F,F] is simple.

On the other hand, if a bi-orderable group is finitely generated (and nontrivial), then its abelianization is infinite, so the group certainly has nontrivial, proper, normal subgroups. This fact is in standard textbooks on orderable groups. (See, for example, Theorem 2.3.1 of the book of Kopytov and Medvedev on *Right-Ordered Groups*.)